# Reading a CSV file into a 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, csv, parsing

I've been trying for days to learn how to create this code. It's a homework example. Beginner Java Final Project. I'm about to rip out my hair, if you could guide me a little, I'd appreciate it. I can't seem to figure out how to parse the csv file into a proper 2d array. The delimiter is a ",". I need to maniuplate one column of data (such as the year), but ignore the first (0,0), (0,1), (0,2) row as it only carries the labels I believe. I'm so lost. What I have prints out the first column, but how would I ignore the label at (0,0), and how would I store this information so I could manipulate it in a method? I don't need help on most of the assignment except how to read the values properly and then be able to manipulate them. Thank you.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class BasicFileIO{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
       String fileName = "Crime.csv";
       File file = new File(fileName);

       try {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
         while (input.hasNext()) {
            String data =  input.nextLine();
            String[] values = data.split(",");
            System.out.println(values[0]);
         }

       }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("Error");
       }
    }
}
```

HERE IS AN IMAGE OF THE CSV FILE. I couldn't upload it. This is how it looks in google docs, but if I open it in atom it's just a file with commas and values (not in cells). 
[CSV screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHvIi.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. You should remove all the instructions for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can read and parse scv files with [apache commons-csv](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html). Here's an example for reading the columns with this library:

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String lastName = record.get("Last Name"); // or you can pass the index of column
    String firstName = record.get("First Name");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works even if not saved in an excel format? The screenshot I saved is how google docs opened it up (looks like its in excel with cells). But if I open it in Atom it's only has commas separating the values.

Comment: Your CSV file uses comma-delimiter format and if you open it with for example, Atom you see the commas, but google docs recognizes this type of file and shows it in pretty format. The answer is yes!